# Looking if the package exist before the getLaunchIntentForPackage

Tags: android

I'm making a special launcher : this launcher show you some determinate apps in your tablet.

For example (sudoku) :

```
button_sudoku.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent();
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.coolandroidappzfree.freesudoku");
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

But imagine if the app com.coolandroidappzfree.freesudoku is not on the tablet ? So the app crash!

I would like to verify before if the app is on the tablett and after the click, install the app if not.

It is possible ?

Thanks

Comment: You should do it the other way around, populate your launcher with the installed apps (you'll need to know because at some point the icons will be needed)

Comment: Thanks but I don't need the icons, it's only buttons to an app in the playstore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
This function launch the appPackageName if is installed in the device or launch the PlayStore if not :

```
public static boolean launchPackage(Context context, String appPackageName){

        List<ApplicationInfo> packages;
        PackageManager pm;

        pm = context.getPackageManager();
        packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages)
        {
            if(packageInfo.packageName.equals(appPackageName))
            {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
                i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(appPackageName);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                context.startActivity(i);
                return true;
            }
        }

        Intent i2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + appPackageName));
        i2.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i2);

        return false;
    }
```